# Ternary operation not executing when toggling Bool value

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a very simple line of code where I am toggling a `Bool` value. If it is true then make it false, if it is false then make it true.

```
if x == true { x = false } else { x = true }
```

I thought this would be a good use for Swift's ternary operator so I tried:

```
x = true ? false : true
```

Xcode flags the `true` at the end and states "Will never execute." When I execute the code, if x is true it toggles to false, but if it is false it does not toggle to true, just as Xcode stated would happen.

While looking into this, I have since realized that the proper way to toggle my `Bool` is to write it like this:

```
x = !x
```

I would still like to know what I was doing wrong. What am I not understanding about the ternary operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your condition is always `true`, rather than the current true/false state of your x variable.

```
x = true ? false : true

    ^^^^
```

As written, this code will always assign `false` to `x` since the condition won't ever fail. When written as a normal if statement, the code you've attempted to use would look like this

```
if true {
    x = false
} else {
    x = true
}
```

Which makes it easier to see why the else clause is never entered. Instead, you should be using the following.

```
x = x ? false : true // x = x == true ? false : true
```

Which assigns x to false if x is true and x to true if x is false.